# Trouble coding up this. Stocastic ODE

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations

[Stocastic ODE Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPDy4.png)

Ok, so I am trying to code up this SDE and I am a bit stuck. I have only been messing with linear ODE's and having trouble finding some resources on how to start this problem. **The second part**.If anyone has some links or dummy code I can work with that would be great. I have posted the question I am referring to above.

Comment: Basically the only difference, is that you need to sample a random Brownian motion dW, and then compute the new value of X. Iterate over time to get a single stochastic process.

Comment: i think that  the concers that you have are not really related to a programming problem and more to the mathmatical background of the question. Try making your self familiar with newtons method for a sistem of non linear equations, a goud source would be  [Numerical Recipes](http://numerical.recipes/)

Comment: What is the numerical method and what is its implicit form? The simplest methods are the Euler-Maruyama and the Milstein methods, both are explicit. Is this talking about the integral form of the SDE that can be seen as implicit form or a fixed-point equation?